# custom queries in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm a beginner in cakephp. I want to create a custom query and retrieve data from a table in cakephp. I have a table called key_uniqueword in the database.

Here is my code:

MODEL:

key_uniqueword.php

```
<?php

class key_uniqueword extends AppModel{


    var $name = 'key_uniqueword';


     public function get()
    {
        $this ->query("SELECT * FROM key_uniqueword");
    }


    }
```

Controller:
ReadingManualsController.php

```
<?php


class ReadingManualsController extends AppController{

    var $name = 'ReadingManuals';


    function index(){

        $this ->set('results',$this ->key_uniqueword-> get());


        }}
```

view:
index.ctp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php


foreach($results as $result)
{

//display results here  
    }

?>
```

But I'm getting this error message.

```
Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object  
File: F:\xampp\htdocs\18\cake\app\Controller\ReadingManualsController.php   
Line: 22
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: Please first follow CakePHP conventions, learn how to properly write the model file http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model file :

KeyUniqueword.php

```
<?php

 class KeyUniqueword extends AppModel{


 public $name = 'KeyUniqueword';
 public $useTable = 'key_uniqueword';  // use own table name  


 public function get()
{
   return $this ->query("SELECT * FROM key_uniqueword");
}


}
```

Your controller:

```
<?php


class ReadingManualsController extends AppController{

  public $name = 'ReadingManuals';

  public $uses = array('KeyUniqueword','ReadingManual') 

  function index(){

    $this ->set('results',$this ->KeyUniqueword-> get());


    }}
```

Comment: yes that worked thank you. but now I'm getting this error.

Table key_uniquewords for model KeyUniqueword was not found in datasource default. But there is a table called key_uniqueword in the database. so should I rename that table as key_uniquewords ?

Comment: yeah, thank you adamp. That worked. I'm confusing because I'm new to cakephp. thank you for helping both of you. :)

Comment: Your get() function does not return anything! Plus, results of a custom query need some massaging, you can't use them directly in a set() call.

Comment: `public $useTable = false;` will make your model not actually use the database, which you don't want to do in this case.  Your problem is that your table doesn't match CakePHP's naming pattern, so it's not finding it.  The standard name for the table would be key_uniquewords (with an s at the end).  If you do not want to use the standard table name, enter the real name of the table as the $useTable property, ex `public $useTable = 'key_uniqueword';`

Comment: In fact, you **shouldn't** use `$this->query()` unless you have a very good reason to do so, because you're bypassing all cake securities and conventions. Instead, use `$this->find('all')` to do a `select *` to your table

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your get() function does not return anything! Also, '$this->key_uniqueword' does not yet exist. There are two main ways to prepare that variable, including:

```
class ReadingManualsController extends AppController{

    var $name = 'ReadingManuals';
    public $uses = array('key_uniqueword');//populates $this->key_uniqueword
    ...
```

Or you can create it before using it, e.g. inside the controller:

```
$this->loadModel('key_uniqueword');
//now you can use $this->key_uniqueword
```

But... You should realy do a simple CakePHP tutorial and follow the conventions. In rare/tricky cases a custom query may be required, but this is not one of them.

Comment: yes you are correct. I need to run a complex sql query in the database. That is why I need a customize sql query.  For an example I wrote this simple query. :)

Comment: There are so many indicators of not using cakephp as designed, It's unlikely the query you want must use query, if you want to know how - ask another question.